# Memory consumption of Parent & child process in Linux

Tags: linux, ram

I am new to the process level memory utilisation analysis, currently i am i get into situation where i am getting confused, i read other blogs those got into indepth where those were making more confused.

the scenario is, in Linux if a process has a child, memory utilisations of both process as below,
-> parent process utilisation is about 390MB
-> child process utilisation is about 350 MB

from this scenario, do we need to consider memory utilisation by both process is about ~400 MB (or) it is ~750 MB,
i please give the info on this scenario

Comment: In general each process gets its own memory space, so it is the sum.  For example when a child process is created from a `fork` a nearly identical copy of the program memory is made and assigned to the child.

Comment: There is something called a copy-on-write fork. This will share the memory pages of the parent with the child until they are changed from one of the sides, then a copy will be created.